# win32ole gem for jruby

Tags: ruby, jruby, win32ole

I'm trying to install jruby gem from http://github.com/bpmcd/win32ole .
it seems that standard

```
jruby -S gem install win32ole
```

doesn't work.

I'm ruby noobie, and so far I understand that this package is not a gem? Am I correct? Do I need to build it? If yes, could you direct me to the docs that explain how to proceed step by step?

Thanks plenty

Comment: oops, correction:
the page address is http://github.com/bpmcd/win32ole

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a much more feature complete version (1.9 API compatible -- 1.8 API++) of win32ole right now: http://www.github.com/enebo/jruby-win32ole.

It is a work in progress but it does much more than the repo you are having issues with.  Some form of this new repo will actually be in JRuby 1.6 when it comes out as well, so you can help us get it into shape if you like.

Update: With both jruby 1.5.5 and the upcoming jruby 1.6.0 you can install 'jruby-win32ole' as a gem.  The Windows installer for 1.6.0 will also include this gem by default.

Comment: Thanks for the gem! Finally working win32ole for jruby...am using it already.

Comment: Confirmed: http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2011/03/jruby-16-now-with-win32ole-goodness.html